# iphone OS 3 Video api

Tags: api, iphone-sdk-3.0, video, editing, iphone-3gs

Does anyone know if its possible to open up the new camera/video API for the new 3gs in the app, similarly to the camera API in 2.2.1? recording functions and all?

but in the same token, is it possible to edit the video recording you just took and edit it?

all the best

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a view controller to do that. You can query it for what type is available. You assign the delegate and it will call it to let you know when you have selected/created a photo or video with the data. Video has a hard limit of 10 minutes.

Comment: thanks erich, and i assume the same will apply for the new 3gs video/camera api. "No extending or modifying the api".

do you happen to have a concise resource off hand that documents the api?

all the best!

Comment: The class of interest is the UIImagePickerController. From their public API: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html